# How to display a specific number of posts per category?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

This question is a duplicate of the following question, which I cannot comment.
And which does not work anymore.

[How can I set the limit number of the posts of a specify category into a page of that category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152921/how-can-i-set-the-limit-number-of-the-posts-of-a-specify-category-into-a-page-of/21234405?noredirect=1#comment31984851_21234405) (answer by Offroff)

I was using this piece of code and it was working fine so far. But since Wordpress latest update (3.8) and for some reason, it does not display the indicated number of posts anymore and it is back number of posts displayed.

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```
/* Modification Offroff - Jan. 3rd
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

function main_query_mods( $query ) {
    if(!$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }
    // show 15 posts per page if category has id 7
    // check http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page
    if ( is_category('21')) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page',15);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'main_query_mods' );
```

Thanks alot for your help!
JHB

Comment: Anything in the site error logs?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it might shed some light http://tommcfarlin.com/pre_get_posts-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hi guys, thanks alot for anwsering. My PHP level is very shallow and to be honest I'm not in a position where i Can clearly identify what is happening. Is there any reason why new Wordpress upgrade could keep this function to work?